# codeigniter - insert return true, without modifying database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I got this update script in a for :

```
if(isset($_POST[$i+1 . '_create_metier'])){
  $new_entry = array(
    'id_parent' => $current[0]->id,
    'work' => $_POST[$i+1 . '_create_metier'],
    'days' => $_POST[$i+1 . '_create_daycount'],
    'price' => $_POST[$i+1 . '_create_price'],
    'cr_date' => date('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
    'user' => ''
  );
  var_dump($new_entry);
  if(!$this->db->insert('meta_parent',$new_entry)){
    echo 'fail';
    $p3 = 0;
  }else{
    echo 'success';
  }
}
```

The `var_dump` return a well filled array for my db structure, and 'success' is printed, implying the query worked.

But i don't get any modification in my DB. It's not my first use of codeigniter and i never had such an issue.

Thanks for help

Comment: You could use `$this->db->last_query()` to see the specific query that's being run. It might give you some insight.

Comment: duplicates may not be allowed are you sure you are not getting any error

Comment: i printed $this->db->last_query() instead of success, it returned a classic query : INSERT INTO `meta_parent` (`id_parent`, `work`, `days`, `price`, `cr_date`, `user`) VALUES ('111', 'LAMP Developer', '3', '1800', '29-06-2012 17:40:23', '')
I check again and again, the meta_parent table ain't getting any new content

Comment: Did you tried to run this query directly on database? It's running successfully? Do you have database debug activated? Look at your application/config/database.php file.

Comment: @user1409885: The point of seeing the actual query, as Gustavo alluded to, is so you can run it outside the context of CodeIgniter. Sometimes it makes it clearer what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: hey, i'm still stucked. The query worklike a charm on phpmyadmin's SQL field, and $this->db->_error_message() is empty, implying again there's no errors. the query returned by last_query works with copy/paste, but not in CI.

Comment: did you recently switch from a dev server to a live server?

Comment: Back on this project, still stuck. Really weird. I'm still on dev server, the line returned after the insert try by $this->db->last_query() show the right query (runs successfully in phpmyadmin). There must be a problem with active record

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the date format, MySQL accept the date in this format: Y-m-d H:i:s

Try replacing

```
'cr_date' => date('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
```

with

```
'cr_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
```

Comment: right tip for the date, but the insert is still blocking. Thank you